# How do I fix my MVC project so that the images display on the website?

Tags: c#, image, model-view-controller

Before everyone marks this as duplicate, I did follow these suggestions:
[CSS images not showing in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575535/css-images-not-showing-in-asp-net-mvc)
[Images Not Showing in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286672/images-not-showing-in-mvc)
and several others.

This is my code:

```
     <img src="~/App_Data/complogo.jpg" class="rounded float-right" alt="complogo">
```

Which works in asp.net, but not in a MVC project. The jpg is located in the folder App_Data in the project folder.
I tried changing the type of image, but not one image works.
When running the project I get that 'broken' image and when hovering the mouse over it tells me 'complogo' as the alt name.
I also went into F12 on Chrome, and it says 404 not found. So what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: By default, IIS considers `App_Data` as "Hidden Segment". You should not store assets that needs to be available to the client in this folder.

Comment: Thanks, I can't mark you as an answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519790/images-that-are-in-app-data-folder-not-shown-in-browser) the *`App_Data`* folder is special and images etc.. in this folder will not be rendered.

Add a separate folder like *`/Content/Images/`* or just *`/Images`* to your project and serve your images from there.